# Select com duas tabelas e uma condição em cada com MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas que não se relacionam. Uma é de relatórios, onde contém nome de professores e sua respectiva matéria, a outra tabela se chama login, aonde contem credenciais de cada professor, seu privilegio e, também, sua respectiva matéria.

A ideia da tabela login é que, com o acesso do professor, ele possa visualizar todos os professores da tabela relatório quando a matéria destes forem igual igual ao do professor logado, e que também o privilegio dos professores seja de professor.

**TABELA LOGIN**

```
id
nome
materia
privilegio
```

**TABELA RELATORIO**

```
nome
materia
```

> QUERY UTILIZADA:

```
SELECT diga_relatorio.nome, diga_relatorio.materia, diga_login.materia 
FROM diga_relatorio, diga_login 
WHERE diga_relatorio.materia='{$_SESSION['digaPrivilegio']}' 
AND diga_login.privilegio='professor' 
GROUP BY diga_relatorio.nome 
ORDER BY diga_relatorio.nome
```

Porém, dessa forma é retornado também os professores com o cargo de coordenador, estando errado, uma vez que a hierarquia seria:

1. COORDENADOR (visualiza todos os outros)
2. SUPERVISOR (visualiza apenas os professores de sua matéria)
3. PROFESSOR (visualiza ele mesmo)

Answer (score 3):

Quando queres relacionar uma tabela com outra através de um campo, tens que usar um `inner join` e mencionar qual é o campo que une as tabelas, caso contrário fazes um `outter join` em que unes tudo com tudo.

Removi o `group by` porque não percebi a utilidade nele na query.

Experimenta:

```
SELECT diga_relatorio.nome, diga_relatorio.materia, diga_login.materia 
FROM diga_relatorio 
INNER JOIN diga_login 
ON diga_relatorio.materia = diga_login.materia 
WHERE diga_relatorio.materia='{$_SESSION['digaPrivilegio']}' 
AND diga_login.privilegio='professor' 
ORDER BY diga_relatorio.nome
```

Comment: O group by está agrupando os professores, uma vez que na tabela relatórios o nome cada repete, pelo menos, 500 vezes.. De qualquer forma irei testar a query e logo darei um feedback. Até então, obrigado!

Comment: a consulta me retorna os mesmos resultados sempre, independente do valor que eu passo para diga_login='...'. A ideia é que o supervisor só consiga enxergar aqueles professores que tenham privilegio de 'professor'.

Comment: A query ficou: "SELECT diga_relatorio.nome, diga_relatorio.materia, diga_login.materia FROM diga_relatorio INNER JOIN diga_login ON diga_relatorio.materia = diga_login.materia WHERE diga_relatorio.materia='{$_SESSION['digaMateria']}' AND diga_login.privilegio='professor' GROUP BY diga_relatorio.nome ORDER BY diga_relatorio.nome"

Comment: Alguem dê um retorno, por favor!

Comment: Não percebo qual é a utilidade da coluna relatório visto que as duas colunas dela se repetem na primeira tabela. De qualquer forma para o que queres experimenta:

`SELECT 
    diga_relatorio.nome,
    diga_relatorio.materia,
    diga_login.materia 
FROM 
    diga_relatorio 
INNER JOIN 
    diga_login 
ON 
    diga_relatorio.materia = diga_login.materia AND
    diga_relatorio.nome= diga_login.nome
WHERE 
    diga_relatorio.materia='{$_SESSION['digaPrivilegio']}' AND 
    diga_login.privilegio='professor' 
ORDER BY 
    diga_relatorio.nome`

Comment: Qual coluna relatório? Desculpe, mas não enxergo a coluna citada.. Ah, a instrução que me passou não retornou resultados. O que estou pensando em fazer é cadastrar todos os professores na tabela de diga_login acompanhado de seu privilégio, uma vez que todos professores da tabela relatorio estará presente em login

Comment: Queria perguntar pela utilidade da tabela relatório.

Confirma isto:
A coluna nome da tabela relatório é igual à coluna nome da tabela login?
A coluna matéria da tabela relatório é igual à matéria da tabela login?

É que me parece que tens os registos da tabela login, duplicados na tabela matéria. 

Caso contrário posta um pedaço da BD que tens, porque está confuso.

Comment: Sim, essas informações são completamente duplicadas, e isso é um problema que já existe a muito tempo. Acontece que esses dados sao preenchidos por aluno, ou seja, uma sala com 40 alunos criará 40 registros para um único professor, uma vez que cada professor é avaliado por cada aluno. Tudo isso foi feito em um excel, e agora estou exportando para o MYSQL, e junto da importação estão chegando diversos erros...